# minimum-stability for package in composer problem

Tags: composer-php

i have a problem with installing a package:

```
composer require adrianclay/xbrl
```

this is the error I get:

```
Could not find package adrianclay/xbrl at any version for your minimum-stability (stable). Check the package spelli
  ng or your minimum-stability
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no releases for the `adrianclay/xbrl` package yet and your `composer.json` requires packages to have a stable release by default. You *could* lower the minimum stability level for every dependency, but usually it is recommended to only rely on dev dependencies explicitly.

In your case, this would mean to run `composer require adrianclay/xbrl:dev-master`.